# Pushpin resize binding zoomlevel

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I'm using WinRT with bing maps and i'm trying to set (programmatically) the RenderTransform value of my pushpin when zooming on map.
I tried this [Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapswindows8/thread/8821757b-a7a5-49af-aa4a-f37699218d31/) but seems that the Windows 8 controls do not support binding to the ZoomLevel property.
does anyone have any either workaround or working example ?
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post here an example that can be used from others if needed. Exploiting your suggestion of using the "ViewChanged" event I wrote this code snippet:

```
    private double Interpolate(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1, double x)
    {
        return y0 * (x - x1) / (x0 - x1) + y1 * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
    }

    private void mapZoom_Event(object sender, ViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double scale;
        foreach (Pushpin currentPin in currentPins)
        {
            double zoom = Map.ZoomLevel;

            scale = interpolate(10, 1 / 2, 18, 3, zoom);

            if (scale < 1)
                scale = 1;

            ScaleTransform pushpinsScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform()
            {
                ScaleX = scale,
                ScaleY = scale
            };
            currentPin.RenderTransform = pushpinsScaleTransform;
        }
    }
```

where ***currentPins*** is an IEnumerable that are in the Map. The ***Interpolate*** method is a simple Lienar function where it should linearly scale the size of your pushpin.

Answer (score 1):

OK resolved: I just associate the [ViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.viewchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event that update also the Zoom Level and in this function I create the RenderTransform property and asspciate it to my Pushpin